# Hypercomplex structures and tangent space decompositions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

For any almost complex manifold we have a decomposition of its tangent space into two subspaces $T = T^{(1,0)} \oplus T^{(0,1)}$. For an almost hypercomplex manifold we have three almost-complex structures $I,J,K$ and so three decompositions
$$
T = T^{(1,0)}_a \oplus T^{(0,1)}_a, ~~~~~~ \textrm{ for } a = I,J,K.
$$
The three almost complex structures are required to give a representation of the quaternions: one asks that
$$
IJK = -1.
$$
What does this explicitly mean for the three decompositions of $T$? I guess there is a simple way to see this condition in terms of the intersections of the various subspaces . . .

Comment: There is nothing particular about $I,J,K$ : there is in fact a sphere $\Bbb{S}^2  $ of complex structures $aI+bJ+cK $ for $a^2+b^2+c^2+0$.

Comment: I think you'll be able to answer this question yourself once you have the correct definitions.  The actual definition is $\mathbb{C}\otimes T = T^{(1,0)}_a\oplus T^{(0,1)}_a$, where $T^{(1,0)}_a = \{ v - i\,av\ |\ v\in T\}$ and  $T^{(0,1)}_a = \{ v + i\,av\ |\ v\in T\}$.